# Render Webpages by Disabling Modernizr Features

Tags: modernizr

How do I render what a webpage will look like without a given Modernizr feature in Chrome?

How do people normally do this? And are there any more advanced ways?

Answer (score 0):

it really depends on how they are being used.

you can manually change the `html` classes if you are trying to see the different styles. You can create a stub `Modernizr` object if its keyed off of that.

But in general, you should be testing in the browser where the results are false. Otherwise you are just sortof-kindof guessing

Comment: Wouldn't this be a cool a super useful program though? You know... how am I supposed to test what happens when certain features don't work? People are actually testing in each different browser?

That seems like a barbaric way to go about the situation.. MAYBE I NEED TO MAKE IT

Comment: I just don't want to make it and watch it not get used because people are possessed by demons that make them not.. sorry gotta say it

Comment: you would test what would happen by using the browser that it doesn't happen in. anything else is just an abstraction